# Recursive function to reverse a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that will reverse a string, I'm pretty sure my basis for the recursion is solid, but I can't get it to work...

Basis: if the length is <= 1 stop.
Else, swap the first and last elements and advance one element forward and reduce the length by 1.

I'm having trouble with reducing the length by 1...

I thought about using `strcat` and add the first element in front with each recursion but it's only good for constants...

**Note2:** I can't change the signature of the function and I can't use any other libraries.

Do not edit the libraries and commands I use here. These are the ones I know and use.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void recuverse(char s[]);
int main()
{
    char s[] = "abcde";
    recuverse(s);
    cout << s << endl;
}

void recuverse(char s[]){
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i;

    if (len <= 1)return;
    else{
        for (i = len-1; i>0; i--){

            swap(s[0], s[i]);

            recuverse(s + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I've purged the comments.  Most of them didn't seem helpful.  Focus on the issue that the OP asked about, and quit worrying about whether or not you can write `void main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop inside the implementation is not necessary: you are performing too many swaps as the result of having that loop. In fact, the whole point of this exercise has been to eliminate the loop.

Fix your implementation by adding an extra function that measures the length of the string once, and then calls a two-argument `recuverse_impl`, like this:

```
void recuverse_impl(char *s, size_t len) {
    // Base case
    if (len < 2) return;
    // Swap elements the two ends
    swap(s[0], s[len-1]);
    // then call recuverse_impl again
    recuverse_impl(s+1, len-2);
}

void recuverse(char s[]){
    recuverse_impl(s, strlen(s));
}
```

If a requirement for whatever reason has been to disallow passing the length explicitly, you could change the implementation as follows:

```
void recuverse(char *s) {
    // Compute the length
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    // Do the base case
    if (len < 2) return;
    // Squirrel away the last element, and replace it with '\0'
    char t = s[len-1];
    s[len-1] = '\0';
    // Make a recursive call
    recuverse(s+1);
    // Now complete the swap
    s[len-1] = s[0];
    s[0] = t;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XVVkoG)

Comment: OP says on another answer that `recuverse` itself must be recursive, and not delegate to another recursive function. I don't know why, but it must.

Comment: @Puppy: dumb requirements don't allow us to give dumb solutions, like argument passing via globals (would do the trick, but hey).

Comment: Thanks for saving me time to say this. @puppy

Comment: Is `size_t` a must here?

Comment: @kuhaku No, but [that's the type returned by `strlen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html). You can use an `unsigned int` or even an `int` instead, and things will continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void recuverse(char s[])
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len <= 1)
        return;
    char c = s[len-1];
    s[len-1] = 0;
    recuverse(s+1);
    s[len-1] = s[0];
    s[0] = c;
}
```

Comment: I never downvote... you can see that in my profile as well.  http://i.imgur.com/eCK986l.png

Comment: @kuhaku: OK, thanks. Anyways, I slightly improved the answer by saving only one character (instead of two) at every step of the recursion. This should reduce stack usage by a magnitude of 2, thus reducing the risk of getting a stack-overflow during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell, this is the only way to accomplish what you ask for with such unreasonable restrictions.

This would be a stupid, *stupid* way to write this function, but I believe it does what was asked for within the specified guidelines.

```
// Reverses a string in place.
// Note: string cannot be a constant, without write permission
void reverse(char s[])
{
    // Get string length
    int len = strlen(s);

    if (len > 2)
    {
        // Save last character
        char lastChar = s[len - 1];

        // Temporarily shorten string by replacing last character
        // with a null-terminator character
        s[len - 1] = '\0';

        // Recursively swap remaining characters
        reverse(s + 1);

        // Swap first and last character
        s[len  - 1] = s[0];
        s[0] = lastChar;
    }
}
```

I consider the approach above to be a bad one because recursion is not the most efficient way to approach this problem. And even if recursion is used, it would be far more efficient to write a separate function for the recursive portion of this code, which could include additional arguments to track state and prevent some of the repeated logic here. Also, it makes no sense to avoid any other libraries, particularly if that includes the libraries that will be part of any C++ application anyway.

Without these restrictions, here's how I might approach writing a reverse function.

```
void reverse(char* s)
{
    char *pEnd = s + (strlen(s) - 1);
    while (s < pEnd)
    {
        char c = *s;
        *s++ = *pEnd;
        *pEnd-- = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it that stupid to write it this way? (you could use `strlen` there btw)

Answer (score 2):

My C solution uses no extra libraries (stdio instead of iostream), and the same function signature.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void recuverse(char s[]){
    char saved;
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len > 1) {
        saved = s[len-1];   // keep last char    
        s[len-1] = 0;       // shorten string
        recuverse(s+1);     // with shorter string
        s[len-1] = s[0];    // replace last char with first
        s[0] = saved;       // replace first char with last
    }                       // job done
}

int main()
{
    char str0 [] = "";      // test with various
    char str1 [] = "a";
    char str2 [] = "ab";
    char str3 [] = "abc";
    char str4 [] = "abcd";

    recuverse (str0);
    printf ("'%s'\n", str0);
    recuverse (str1);
    printf ("'%s'\n", str1);
    recuverse (str2);
    printf ("'%s'\n", str2);
    recuverse (str3);
    printf ("'%s'\n", str3);
    recuverse (str4);
    printf ("'%s'\n", str4);
}
```

Program output

```
''
'a'
'ba'
'cba'
'dcba'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I have understood what you need that is what approach you are trying to implement.

You could write the function like

```
void recuverse( char s[] )
{
    recuverse( s , std::strlen( s ) );
}

void recuverse( char s[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        std::swap( s[0], s[n-1] );
        recuverse( s + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}
```

But it is a **wrong** solution because it is not function `void recuverse( char s[] );` that is a recursive function. It is function `void recuverse( char s[], size_t n );` that is recursive. But according to your assignment it is function `void recuverse( char s[] );`  that shall be recursive.

So the only correct solution is the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

char * recuverse( char s[] )
{
    if ( *s  )
    {
        char *p = s;

        do
        {
            std::swap( *p, *( p + 1) );
        } while ( *p++ );

        recuverse( s );

        std::swap( *p, *( p - 1 ) );
    }

    return s;
}


int main() 
{
    char s[] = "abcde";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << recuverse( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
abcde
edcba
```

This recursive function uses neither standard function except `std::swap` that you can also substitute for your code.:)

I prefer that the function would have return type `char *` the similar way as standard C string functions. If you want that the function would have return type `void` then it will look like

```
void recuverse( char s[] )
{
    if ( *s  )
    {
        char *p = s;

        do
        {
            std::swap( *p, *( p + 1) );
        } while ( *p++ );

        recuverse( s );

        std::swap( *p, *( p - 1 ) );
    }
}
```

For to understand how this reverse function works without standard function `strlen`  let consider its operations step by step using simplified example "abc".

So we have string with terminating zero

```
abc\0
```

which I will write as `abc0`

The while loop

```
while ( *p++ ) ...
```

swaps characters until it will swap the terminating zero.

In the first recursive call the loop is doing the following

```
abc0
bac0
bca0
bc0a
```

---

Now the function calls itself but now the string looks like

bc0

So in the loop there will be

```
bc0
cb0
c0b
```

---

In the next recursive call the argument will be

c0

In the loop the two characters are swapped

```
0c
```

So at last the function is called with an empty string. So it simply returns the control to the caller and the caller swaps last characters of the string

Take into account that the whole string now looks like

```
0cba
```

We need to move the terminating zero tp its valid position at the end of the string. This is done with the swap after the loop.

```
0c => c0
--------
c0b => cb0
-----------
cb0a => cba0
```

That is all.:)

Comment: Can you add some explanation on `while ( *p++ );` please?

Comment: plus 1, nice inefficient solution, like random sort :)

Comment: This is very interesting but I also don't get how the while loop doesn't execute with `*p == 0` because of the post increment.

Comment: @Lashane It is a splendid solution. I never see such a solution before that a string could be reversed without strlen.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `do .. while (*p)` is kinda strlen

Comment: Ah is it because the moving `\0` bumps into poniter `p`?

Comment: @Galik You are right. Is not it interesting solution is it?:)

Comment: @Lashane Not the same. The loop swaps characters. There is entirely different idea.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I understood idea and I understood difference, just pointed that some kind of looping till `\0` symbol (what basically strlen does) still present

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I still don't see what `while ( *p++ );` does here... what's the point of advancing the pointer of `p` all the way to `0`?

Comment: I got it. Why not a regular `while` loop or `for` loop?

Comment: It changes the length of the string by moving the `\0` terminator towards the beginning. Its a work of genius, though not particularly efficient :)

Comment: @kuhaku because we need to swap symbols first and then compare, to swap 0 properly

Comment: @kuhaku It swaps sequentially characters in the string until the first letter will be the last letter of the string. That is if you have string abc0 then the loop swap a and b and you get bac0. Then it swap next two characters  a and c and you get bca0 . Now it swaps a and 0 and you get bc0a. So a now moved from the first position to the last. The next recursive call will deal with string bc0 and move b to the position before the last position. The problem is that you need to place 0 in its correct position This is done by the last separate swap.

Comment: @kuhaku Try to follow the program with pensil and paper step by step. It will be more clear. For example take at first string like "a" that is that contains only character 'a' and terminating zero '\0' and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

here is proper version of recursive reverse:

```
void reverse(char *s, char *e) {
    if (s < e) {
        char t = *s;
        *s = *e;
        *e = t;
        reverse(s+1, e-1); // here is length is decreased by 2
    }
}

void recuverse(char s[]) {
    int len = strlen(s);

    reverse(s, s+len-1);
}
```

Comment: Is this tested? Doesn't your use of `swap` swap the pointers instead of the characters?

Comment: @kuhaku function signature is not changed

Comment: This isn't a recursive function, it's an outline for a recursive function.

Comment: No, it definitely is a recursive function. Impossible to define usefully in C because swap(*s, *e) is unimplementable meaningfully there, but it definitely is recursive.

Comment: @Puppy is `recuverse` recursive? no then it's not recursive. Stop acting like a dick.

Comment: @kuhaku: People are trying to help you. Maybe you should stop acting like a dick. This *is* a recursive function. And Puppy, what is your problem with the revised code? Without testing it, it appears correct to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood `recuverse` is supposed to be recursive, implements a call inside it to a recursive function still doesn't make it recursive.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Take a look at the `swap` call, it's unimplementable.

Comment: @Puppy: I've seen it. What do you have against being explicit about your issue with the revised code?

Comment: I was quite explicit about it. I state it right up there. "Impossible to define usefully because swap(*s, *e) is unimplementable".

Comment: @Puppy in pure C we need to define swap to accept pointers, but here is obviously c++, where references are used, anyway - doesn't relate to main OP question

Comment: @Lashane: Well, actually, we're in C, not C++, the OP simply doesn't quite seem to understand what the difference is, why it matters, or where the distinction occurs.

Comment: @Puppy yes, OP doesn't understand difference, but again - it is not related to question, he/she is using c++ for sure

Comment: @Puppy It's true, I don't know the difference, from what I understand I learn C with C++ commands and libraries that's why it's a sort of a combination as I told you.

Comment: @Puppy: I have no idea what you're going on about. The revised code doesn't use `swap(*s,*e)`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf just to stop useless discussion whether it c or c++, I've decided just "implement" swap which will work in both languages

Comment: I just noticed that although this doesn't answer the exact requirements, it's still an excellent and very simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is not changing the signature, but it is using `std::swap` to swap s[begin] and s[end] until it reaches the middle. To accomplish recursion and also keep the signature, you can (doens't mean you should) declare begin, mid and length as global variables:

```
int beg = 0;
int len = 0;
int mid = 0;

void recuverse(char s[]) {
    if (beg == 0) { // this block runs one time.
        len = strlen(s)-1;
        mid = len / 2;
    }
    if (beg == mid)
        return;
    swap(s[beg], s[len]);
    ++beg, --len;
    recuverse(s);
}
```

Output: edcba

Comment: @kuhaku: You can just call this function from a function with your preferred signature. Note that that signature does not support a direct recursive solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `string` argument, and why on Venus do you call it `n`?

Comment: @0xB00B5 Thanks but it isn't recursive.

Comment: @kuhaku, edited again for recursion but you should know there are much better ways to accomplish this, if you were allowed to have another signature.

Comment: @0xB00B5 yes I'm aware of that, it'll be more easy too. Thanks again, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

if you are allowed to use static variable, try this

```
void recuverse(char s[]){
    static int e;
    int z=strlen(s)-e++;           // z is the number of characters to be evaluated
    if(z>1){    
        char t=*(s+z-1);
        *(s+z-1)=*s;
        *s=t;
        recuverse(s+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remark that `mirror(cs) = cat(mirror(s),c)` (`c` being a char and `s` a string) then :

```
void rev(char *s) {
  if (*s==0) return;
  rev(s+1);
  sprintf(s,"%s%c",s+1,*s);
}
```

Comment: OP says: no additional library functions.

Comment: Ok, change the `sprinttf` call to the right `while` loop... `char c = *s; while (*(s+1)) { *s = *(s+1); s++; } *s = c;`

Answer (score 0):

Below C++ implementation do recursively reverse a string

Here Base Case is finding the NULL character in string

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


    void reverse(string s,long i){


        if(s[i] == '\0')
        return;


        reverse(s,i+1);

        cout<<s[i];
        return;
    }

    int main(){


        string s;

        cin>>s;


        reverse(s,0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *"can't change the signature of the function"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string reverse(std::string inString)
{
    if (inString.empty()) return "";  // the base case
    
    // push last_char from inString onto the stack
    char last_char = inString.back();  
   
    // remove last char from inString (last pop will create base case)
    inString.pop_back(); 

    // recursive call with shortened inString
    std::string outString = reverse(inString); 
    
    /* pop lastChar(s) off of the stack, inserting in zero index of 
       OutString as they come off the stack. */
    return outString.insert(0, 1, last_char);  
}


int main()
{
    std::string s( "Hello bobaloogie" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse(s) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Hello stack Overflow
wolfrevO kcats olleH
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void recuverse(char *s, int right);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "abcde";
    recuverse(s , 0);
    cout << s << endl;
}

void recuverse(char *s, int right){ // Here right is the position of the right position(from right to left) of character with which you will swap
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i;

    if (len <=right)return;

    swap(s[0], s[len-1-right]);

    recuverse(s + 1, right+1);
}
```

Comment: *"can't change the signature of the function*"

Comment: Please don't try this; this code is illegal, since `main` is never allowed to return `void`.